# SQL Joining three tables with same foreign key not combining table 2 and 3 data

Tags: sql-server, left-join, outer-join

What I am trying to accomplish is joining three tables, that have the same foreign key. But I would like to show the detail from table 2 and table 3 without combining them into a single row. Below you can see the screen capture of the data that is being returned. The InvoiceAmount is printing the same amount multiple times. "Name" is from the First table which is also the foreign key(CC1) in the other two tables. "InvoiceAmount" and "Description" are from the second table, and "NetAmount" is from the Third Table.

If "InvoiceAmount" and "Description" has a value then "NetAmount" will be null

If "NetAmount" has a value then "InvoiceAmount" and "Description" will be null

[image]

Below is how I would like the data to be printed in the select if it is possible. I don't know if I have to create a view, or if it is possible to do it through a Select query, or if is even possible at all.

```
Name         InvoiceAmount       Description            NetAmount 
19-SHOP        -10041.98         BULKITEMTRANSFER        NULL  
19-SHOP         NULL               NULL                   84.840625
19-SHOP         NULL               NULL                   109.8613
19-SHOP         NULL               NULL                   110.1601
19-SHOP         NULL               NULL                   154.5323
19-SHOP         NULL               NULL                   187.5742
```

Attached below is the SQL that I have now, and it is doing exactly what I'm telling it to do, but I just can't figure out, or find anywhere how to print the data like I have shown above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

`SELECT j.Name,  a.InvoiceAmount, a.Description, p.NetAmount FROM Job AS j
LEFT OUTER JOIN
APInvoiceBatchDetail AS a 
ON a.CC1 = j.Name 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
PPEReport AS p 
ON p.CC1 = j.Name`

Below is the screen capture for the first table 'Job'

[image]

Below is the screen capture for the second table 'APInvoiceBatchDetail'

[image]

Below is the screen capture for the third table 'PPERecord'

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Code questions need a [mcve]. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT j.Name,  a.InvoiceAmount, a.Description, null as NetAmount 
FROM Job AS j
JOIN APInvoiceBatchDetail AS a ON a.CC1 = j.Name 

union all

SELECT j.Name,  null as InvoiceAmount, null as Description, p.NetAmount 
FROM Job AS j
JOIN PPEReport AS p ON p.CC1 = j.Name
```

if you need a order you can do it like this:

```
SELECT Name, InvoiceAmount, Description, NetAmount
FROM (
  SELECT j.Name,  a.InvoiceAmount, a.Description, null as NetAmount,
         1 as ord 
  FROM Job AS j
  JOIN APInvoiceBatchDetail AS a ON a.CC1 = j.Name 

  union all

  SELECT j.Name,  null as InvoiceAmount, null as Description, p.NetAmount,
         2 as ord 
  FROM Job AS j
  JOIN PPEReport AS p ON p.CC1 = j.Name
) X
ORDER BY X.ORD, X.Name
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I had no idea that you could do the "null as" to satisfy the union all